# Punctured disk in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, epsilon-delta

According to the book I'm reading, the punctured disk is neither open nor closed. [image]

I understand why it isn't open, namely because it contains boundary points. But why is it not a closed set? All the points |z| = 1 or the boundary points are contained in the set.

Unless they consider the point |z| = 0 to be a boundary point. Then the conclusion to why it is not closed is that the set does not contain the point|z| = 0.

Is my reasoning correct or is there some other reason I'm not seeing as to why it would not be closed.

Also, in this context, just to clear up confusion, the set of points that make up the unit circle |z| = 1 is a closed set, right? Even though it doesn't contain points |z| < 1. I'm unsure about the meaning of the closure of a set and a closed set. Thank you.

Comment: Review carefully the definition of a closed set.

Comment: I have, and I suspect it is because it does not include the point z = 0. Which I suppose is a single boundary point, correct?

Comment: According the Chruchill's complex analysis, "a set is closed if it contains all of its boundary points." So for example, |z| = 1 is a closed set. A set that contains the points |z| = 1 and the points |z| < 1 is a closed set as well?

Answer (score 3):

A set is closed if its complement is open.

The complement of the punctured disk consists of a neighbourhood of $\infty$, which is open, and a single point $\{0\}$.

By definition of open sets, if $\{0\}$ was open, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists z  \neq 0, |z - 0| < \epsilon \land z \in \{0\}$, but that is impossible. Hence the complement of the punctured disk is not open.

Comment: Thank you that was insightful. That clears up some stuff about Marsden's book.

Answer (score 0):

z=0 is a boundary point, since you cannot define a deleted neighborhood which contain points only belonging to the set, so it is not an interior point. Neither can you define a deleted neighborhood which contain points only not belonging to the set, so it is not closed either. Then by definition it is a boundary point.